# How to use TargetUpdated in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to use TargetUpdated in WPF.

The following is a snippet from my XAXML file.

```
  <TextBlock TargetUpdated="QuantityRequested_TargetUpdated">
    <TextBlock.Text>
      <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} Quantity {1} {2}">
        <Binding Path="ProductName" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
        <Binding Path="QuantityRequested" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
        <Binding Path="PreCouponQtyAdjPrice" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
      </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
  </TextBlock>
```

I have the following in my code behind file in my view class.

```
public partial class CheckoutView : UserControl
{
    /* Additioal code omitted. */

    public void QuantityRequested_TargetUpdated(
        Object sender, DataTransferEventArgs args)
    {
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=Failed to create a 'TargetUpdated' from the text 'QuantityRequested_TargetUpdated'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
...
Inner Exception 1:
ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.
```

**Note:** I updated the question to incorporate changes suggested by @BionicCode. The changes made no difference. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please don't modify the existing code if you want to update it with a new version that incorporates some suggestions. It could make an existing answer appear to be off-topic, especially when you remove code and during the course of a discussion. Just append the updated version to your existing question.

Comment: @BenKey: When do you expect your event handler to be invoked? What is not working?

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry to say, but everything is wrong with your example.

1. You XAML syntax is wrong.
   There are two ways of defining a `Binding` in XAML: *attribute syntax* (using the markup extension `Binding`) or *property element syntax* (by explicitly defining a `Binding` object as object node).

***Attribute syntax***

The `Binding` is defined using it as markup extension (`Binding` also extends `MarkupExtension`). The properties of `Binding` are set using the markup extension syntax:

```xml
<Object Property="{Binding Source}" />
```

***Property element syntax***

`Binding` is defined as a XAML object nested in to a property. In this case the properties of `Binding` itself are set using the attribute syntax:

```xml
<Object>
  <Object.Property>
    <Binding Path="QuantityRequested"
             NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
  <Object.Property>
<Object>
```

2. The `Binding.TargetUpdated` is an attached event. You must therefore attach it to a `DependencyObject` or use the alias defined by `FrameworkElement` (`FrameworkElement.TargetUpdated`).
   `Binding` is not a `DependencyObject`, so attaching the property to `Binding` won't compile.

   Note, `Binding` itself does not raise this event, meaning it is not the event source. The `Binding.Target` (the `TextBlock` in your case) is the source of this event. The event is actually *triggered* by the `BindingExpression`, created for the associated `Binding`, using a corresponding invocation method of the `FrameworkElement` (the `Binding.Target`), which then finally raises the event.

   However, all that matters is that since it is the `TextBlock` that raises the event, you must register the event handler with the `TextBlock` (and not `Binding`like in your wrong example).

   The following examples assume that you have a `TextBlock_TargetUpdated` event handler defined.

**Example that uses the `FrameworkElement.TargetUpdated` alias event (instance event)**

```xml
<TextBlock TargetUpdated="TextBlock_TargetUpdated">
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <Binding Path="QuantityRequested"
             NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
  <TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

**Example that uses the original `Binding.TargetUpdated` attached event**

```xml
<TextBlock Binding.TargetUpdated="TextBlock_TargetUpdated">
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <Binding Path="QuantityRequested"
             NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
  <TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

3. Next is the event handler: the event handler must be an *instance* member. It can't be static (class member):

```cs
private void QuantityRequested_TargetUpdated(Object sender, DataTransferEventArgs args)
{
}
```

4. To make it finally work, you also have to fix your `Binding.StringFormat` value.
   If there is no text preceding the first placeholder, you must start the format string with an empty curly brace `{}`:

```xml
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} Quantity {1} {2}">
```

Putting everything together, the final fix could look like this:

```xml
<TextBlock TargetUpdated="QuantityRequested_TargetUpdated">
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} Quantity {1} {2}"
                  NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True">
      <Binding Path="ProductName" />
      <Binding Path="QuantityRequested" />
      <Binding Path="PreCouponQtyAdjPrice" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

```cs
private void QuantityRequested_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: What does the following mean? "The Binding.TargetUpdated is an attached event. You must therefore attach it to a DependencyObject or use the alias defined by FrameworkElement (FrameworkElement.TargetUpdated)." Is it enough to simply define the member file in the code behind file or is some additional magical incantation needed?

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. I also updated the question to reflect the changes I made. I am getting the same error. Can you provide more information.

Comment: In your example you tried to set the TargetUpdated event on the Binding. This is not possible as Binding does not have such an (instance) event. The event is defined as an attached event. Attached events like attached properties can only be set on a type that extends DependencyObject. I was trying to explain why your code can never work/compile. You must attach the event to the TextBlock (like in my example). TextBlock extends DependencyObject. Also it's the TextBlcok that raises the event, if this makes more sense.

Comment: Please take compiler errors more seriously. You always write code that the XAML designer will instantly complain *before* even executing the code. `<TextBlock.Text TargetUpdated="Quantit...` is invalid code/syntax.  `<TextBlock.Text>` is property notation syntax. It's a property (the `Text` property) and not an object. `<TextBlock>` is the object. You can't attach attached properties or attached events to a property. This doesn't even make sense. Take a closer look how I implemented the example. You must read more carefully. Details matter.

Comment: [Attached events overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/events/attached-events-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: [Attached properties overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/attached-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: [XAML Syntax In Detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#object-element-syntax)

Comment: If you have problems to understand the concept of attached events, you can focus on the alias instance event (see explanation in my answer). TextBlock inherits a TargetUpdated event from FrameworkElement. Just use this event as you usually would.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show the syntax difference between the instance event and the attached event (see 2.).

Comment: In section two of your answer you make the same mistake as the Microsoft documentation, In that section it is all XAML with no C#. You have proposed two different methods of associating TextBlock_TargetUpdated as the TargetUpdated handler for the TextBlock but there is no C#. One extra sentence for each of the possibilities in section 2 may be enough.

Comment: @BenKey What do you mean? There is no C#? You must and only can define event handlers in C# (except for event triggers). I think it should be clear how to handle events in XAML in the first place. Handlers are always defined in code-behind.

Comment: Ok, you ask me to explicitly state that the handler is defined in the code-behind? But isn't this basic knowledge?

Comment: The examples even use your original method names.

Comment: I have added a hint. I hope you are now able to understand the examples.

Comment: First, my examples use QuantityRequested_TargetUpdated consistently in XAML and C#. You use TextBlock_TargetUpdated in you XAML and no where in C#. In the one section that has C# code you do use QuantityRequested_TargetUpdated.  Was this an error or your part or is there some C# magical incantaition you did no share that defines TextBlock_TargetUpdated. Second, I am still getting the errors despite making every change you suggests.

Comment: A link to am massive web page does not help. How hard is it to say this is the C# code to define TextBlock_TargetUpdated? Is it just a method? Is it a variable? What is it?

Comment: In you answer, is section 2, which starts at "2. The Binding.TargetUpdated" and ends at "3. Next is the event handler" there is no C# code. In addition, yiou are using TextBlock_TargetUpdated in section 2, which is not what used in my example and in you are using QuantityRequested_TargetUpdated in section 3. This is what I meant when I said in section 2 of your answer there is no XC#. That section is just XAML. I know that C# is required., but the questsion is what C#.

Comment: *"A link to am massive web page does not help. How hard is it to say this is the C# code to define TextBlock_TargetUpdated? Is it just a method? Is it a variable? What is it?"* - Now it's starting to get ugly. I gave you the link because you obviously lack some very fundamental understanding. You can't learn without reading. You are also free to lookup your own sources. It was just a recommendation, which itself is a kind move to post.

Comment: My examples assume that you have at least the understanding how to register event handlers in XAML. But you obviously haven't. It was not my intention to give you a lesson or write a full tutorial.

Comment: I think the example is pretty clear. Even if you don't understand a word, you should be able to compare my examples with yours.

Comment: I still have no idea how to get TargetUpdated to work when event is specified in XAML.  What actually got it to work for me was when I assigned the event in C# using "element.TargetUpdated += OnTargetUpdated;" When it was in XAML I consistently got the error.

Comment: Also, the NotifyOnTargetUpdated attribute needs to be on the MultiBinding element, not on the Binding elements.

Comment: I have created a small example to prove that my suggestions work. So you must be still doing something wrong which requires further review in order to be able to help.

Comment: I have added the final example to the answer that puts everything together based on your code.